# Why is all my data being purged before output?

Tags: c++, string, file-io, output

I've written a function that undoes an algorithm. the algorithm is good, assumably. That is tangent, tho to this question. Why does my output not go to file? I need to know what I've done that is purging the strings in the function from having content in them.

I've tried move strings around, and use different places for the output. I also tried to print to screen. So, somewhere I'm resetting the strings needed for output. I expected the data to at least go to file. But it isn't working. It doesn't print anything.

```
string retrieve(string buf, ofstream& out)
{
    uint8_t i_cnt = 0;
    uint64_t space_bin = 0;
    string section_str = "";
    uint64_t i = 0;
    // while (buf.length() > 0)
    {
        i = 0;
        string c = "";
        for (uint8_t x : buf)
        {
            c = (bitset<8>(x).to_string() + c);
        }

        while (i < c.length())
        {
            i = 0;
            // uint16_t B = bitset<8>(c.substr(0,8)).to_ulong();

            // c = c.substr(8);
            // if (B == 129 || B == 134)
            // {
            //  B = bitset<8>(c.substr(0,8)).to_ulong();
            //  cout << "!!" << flush;
            //  section_str = bitset<7>(B).to_string() + section_str;
            //  c = c.substr(8);
            // }
            // else if (B == 130 || B == 135)
            {
                uint16_t B = bitset<8>(c.substr(0,8)).to_ulong();
                space_bin = bitset<8>(B).to_ulong();
                c = c.substr(8);
                while (space_bin > 0)
                {
                    section_str += bitset<8>(0).to_string();
                    space_bin--;
                }
                cout << "??" << flush;
                B = bitset<12>(c.substr(0,12)).to_ulong();
                section_str += bitset<12>(B).to_string();
                c = c.substr(12);
            }
            
        }
        
        string v_Temp = "";
        while (section_str.length() > 0)
        {
            v_Temp += (char)(bitset<8>(section_str.substr(0,8%(section_str.length()+1)))).to_ulong();
            section_str = section_str.substr(8%(section_str.length()+1));
        }

        return v_Temp;
    }
}

bool recollect(ifstream& in) {

    stringstream rd;
    rd << in.rdbuf();
    in.close();
    string buf = rd.str();
    rd.str("");
    uint64_t buf_len = buf.length(), bin_len = 0, buf_left = buf_len;
    uint8_t fn_s = buf.find("START---"); // 8 chars long
    uint8_t fn_t = buf.find("-----------------S",18 + fn_s + 8);
    string full_size_str = buf.substr(18, fn_s-18);
    uint64_t full_size = 0;
    cout << full_size_str << " " << flush;
    uint8_t fss = full_size_str.length();
    for (int8_t i = 1 ; i < fss ; i++)
    {
        full_size += (10*i) * (int)(full_size_str[i-1] - 48);
    }
    buf = buf.substr(18+fss);
    fn_s = buf.find("START---") + 8; // 8 chars long
    fn_t = buf.find("-----------------S");
    uint32_t filename_len = buf.find("-----------------S");
    string filename_str = buf.substr(fn_s,fn_t-fn_s);
    cout << filename_str << " " << flush;
    ofstream out {filename_str.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc };
    buf = buf.substr(fn_s+18+fss+fn_t);
    uint64_t eOf = buf.find("-----------------END--------------------S");
    
    while (string::npos != buf.find((char)(136)))
    {
        string temp = buf.substr(0,buf.find((char)(136))+1);
        string return_str = retrieve(temp, out);
        cout << return_str;
        buf = buf.substr(temp.length());
    }
    
    return (buf.length() > 41);
} 

void collect(ifstream& in, ofstream& out, string outfilename) {

    stringstream rd;
    rd << in.rdbuf();
    in.close();
    string buf = rd.str();
    rd.str("");
    long long unsigned int p = 0, buf_len = buf.length(), bin_len = 0;
    uint64_t buf_left = buf_len;
    string bin = "";
    uint32_t buf_str_len = 6400000;
    const int MAX_BITS = 2048;
    out << "-----------------S" << buf.length() << "START---" << outfilename << "-----------------S";
    for ( ; 0 < buf.length() ; ) {

        string bf = (buf.length() > buf_str_len) ? buf.substr(0, buf_str_len) : buf;
        
        while (bf.length() > 0)
        {
            string b = (bf.length() >= MAX_BITS) ? bf.substr(0,MAX_BITS) : (bf.length() > 0) ? bf : "";
            buf_left -= MAX_BITS;
            string c = "";
            for (uint8_t x : b)
            {
                c.append(bitset<8>(x).to_string());
            }
            int8_t i = 8, j = 5, i_cnt = 0, q = 0;
            uint64_t ch = 0;
            while (c.length() > 0)
            {
                
                if (i > (c.length()))
                    i = c.length();
                ch = bitset<64>(c.substr(c.length()-(i%(c.length()+1)))).to_ullong();
                while (ch > 0)
                {
                    if (ch%256 == 0)
                    {
                        i_cnt++;
                        ch >>= 8;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bin += (char)(i_cnt) + (char)(ch%256);
                        i_cnt = 0;
                        ch >>= 8;
                    }
                }
                i += 12;
                c = c.substr(0,c.length()-(12%(c.length()+1)));
                if (i >= (c.length()))
                    c = "";
            }
            ch = bitset<63>(c.substr(c.length()-(12%(c.length()+1)))).to_ullong();
            while (ch > 0)
            {
                if (ch%128 == 0)
                {
                    i_cnt++;
                }
                if (i_cnt == 0)
                {
                    bin += (uint8_t)(134) + (uint8_t)(ch%128);
                }
                else
                {
                    bin += (uint8_t)(135) + (uint8_t)(i_cnt) + (uint8_t)(ch%128);
                    i_cnt = 0;
                }
                ch >>= 7;
            }
            bin += (uint8_t)(136);
            if (bin.length() > 100000)
            {
                out << bin;
                bin_len += bin.length();
                bin.clear();
            }
            bf = (bf.length() > MAX_BITS) ? bf.substr(MAX_BITS) : "";
        }
        out << bin;
        bin_len += bin.length();
        bin.clear();
        cout << "[ [ Left:Out " << buf_left << ":" << bin_len << " | " << (bin_len/(double)(buf_len - buf_left)*100) << "% | " << (((buf_len-buf_left)/(double)(buf_len))*100) << "% ]  ]\t\t\r" << flush;
        buf = (buf.length() > buf_str_len) ? buf.substr(buf_str_len) : "";
    }
    cout << "[ [ Left:Out 0:" << bin_len << " | " << (bin_len/(double)(buf_len - buf_left)*100) << "% | " << (((buf_len-buf_left)/(double)(buf_len))*100) << "% ]  ]\t\t\r" << flush;
    bin_len += bin.length();
    out << bin;
    out << "-----------------END--------------------S";
    return;
}
```

Comment: when you remove everything from the code but only keep the output, do you see something in the file? If not you can look at that code and need not consider all that you just removed. Its called [mcve]

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on the line that you open your file, and step through the code line-by-line in a debugger?  Is it possible you are opening the file multiple times and wiping out the previous contents when you open the file?

Comment: You never enter the `while (section_str.length() > 0)` loop. If you had, it would never terminate (`substr` returns a new string).

Comment: @molbdnilo I've been at this for hours. All day. In fact 12 years. Sorry. I have 129, 130, 135, and 134 as markers. Unfortunately, as is the case, I can only capture the first tag and then they disappear. I'll update what I have here, and probably add the compression routine.